# How can I prevent Visual Studio (2019) from opening "VS Debug Console" and just use the old .NET Core Host console?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

It seems like with VS 2019 (Enterprise?), there is a new type of console application host available that even stays unclosed after I stop debugging. When starting multiple projects, the first console application that starts up will be of this new type.

[image]

I am searching for a way to prevent VS to use this console for the "main"-project, and simply use the same console for every project I am starting. I have started the same solution with 4 ASP.NET Core projects inside VS 2017 and Visual Studio did not start any console with 'dotnet.exe' in the title. So for is seems like this is a new thing in 2019.

The reason for this question is because I am having some trouble with this new console. The project often does not start at all and the colors of the console are all green. But that shouldn't be topic of this question.

So is there a way to prevent Visual Studio 2019 from starting this new console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a setting under `Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops` that will restore the old behavior.

Comment: Thanks! What an misleading option description, is should be called `Use host console instead of VsDebugConsole`