# Why PrepareConstrainedRegions method does not work in c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clr, cer, constrained-execution-reg

I read the book "CLR via C#" by Jeffrey Richter. In chapter 20, there is a code example demonstrating usage of Constrained Execution Regions (CERs):

```
private static void Demo2() {
 // Force the code in the finally to be eagerly prepared
 RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions(); // System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespace
 try {
 Console.WriteLine("In try");
 }
 finally {
 // Type2’s static constructor is implicitly called in here
 Type2.M();
 }
}
public class Type2 {
 static Type2() {
 Console.WriteLine("Type2's static ctor called");
 }
 // Use this attribute defined in the System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution namespace
 [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
 public static void M() { }
}
```

And the following text:

> Now, when I run this version of the code, I get the following output.
>
> ```
> Type2's static ctor called
> In try
> ```

But when I run this code I get the following output no matter if I use CERs or not:

```
In try
Type2's static ctor called
```

So, `Type2` constructor is getting called *after* `try` block (breaking the meaning of CERs usages, as I understand it).

What can be possible reason of this?

**EDIT:**
I'm using .Net Core 3.1 and VS Enterprise 2019 Preview
Version 16.6.0 Preview 3.0, my code is:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;

public sealed class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Demo2();
    }
    private static void Demo2()
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareConstrainedRegions();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In try");
        }
        finally
        {
            Type2.M();
        }
    }
}
public class Type2
{
    static Type2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type2's static ctor called");
    }
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    public static void M() { }
}
```

By the way, `Type2` class can be inside the `Program`, it does not change the output.

Comment: Can you show the relavent, where you are calling the method

Comment: FWIW, it works for my (.NET Fx 4.6.2, 4.7.2 and .NET Core 3.1). BTW, your code isn't compilable. It is missing the `using` directives. You might want to indicate which .NET version you are using.

Comment: I'm using .Net Core 3.1, as you did

Comment: @helgez,I test your code on.NET Core3.1, .NET Core3.0, .NET Core2.1, .NET Core2.0, PrepareConstrainedRegions() doesn’t work, and in .NET Core2.2, other errors occurred, but in .NET Framework4.7.2, .NET Framework4.6.1, PrepareConstrainedRegions() worked. I think it is the platform problem. You can try .net framework to test the code.

Answer (score 1):

*(This is not the full answer to what is actually going on here, but it might help you)*

Your problem is most likely that you run your process from within Visual Studio (using CTRL+F5). It is then launched via `VsDebugConsole.exe`, which then starts your process (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56002509/21567)).

For whatever reason - that would need to be researched - it *looks* as if CERs are not honored when running in this way.

What you could do to validate, is attempt to run your program directly from the command prompt / console.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried to compile my code with csc.exe, and it worked as should be. However, in VS I'm selecting "Release", starting app without debugging (ctrl + f5), and (for some reason, even though I can't even debug by breakpoint and etc) it just does not show me normal behaviour. I think there should be some other setting/option in VS that would make this (and maybe something other?) work, but I don't know where to find it. 
P.S Setting from answer to linked post does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from Microsoft's article about [Constrained Execution Regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/performance/constrained-execution-regions):

> CER is only supported in .NET Framework. This article doesn't apply to
> .NET Core or .NET 5 and above.